# When creating an excel destination, it creates the excel file when creating a table

Tags: excel, ssis

I noticed that when creating an excel destination in my SSIS package, when I setup the excel destination I have to create a new table in the settings.
When I create a new table and select that in the drop down, I noticed it actually creates the excel file in the destination folder.

I'm referring to the create table popup where it looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `MySheet` (

    `UserID` INT,
    ...
    ...
)
```

What I noticed is, if I edit the CREATE TABLE snippet and save it, it doesn't actually change my .dtsx file.  So in TFS, there is no change in the file.
This means the excel file that it creates is very important, but if I deploy this to production it won't have that excel file in the destination folder to read from.

Is this how the excel destination works??

[image]

Below is when I am creating the sheet in excel, and defining the layout of the table.  When I do this, it creates the file in the destination folder.  **It doesn't actually modify my .dtsx file at all so it looks like SSIS relies on this file being creating in order to know how to pump the data from my oledb source into excel.**

[image]

> So currently if I delete the file in the destination folder, I get an
>   error in my excel destination and I have to recreate the table which
>   then creates the file again.

Comment: What exactly are you doing when you "edit the CREATE TABLE snippet and save it"?    Edit it where?   Save it how?   Describe it step-by-step.   Although, actually it might be better to forget what you're doing and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TabAlleman I added some screenshots.  I am simply calling a proc, taking the results and saving this to an excel file.

Comment: Ok, so which do you WANT it to do:   do you want the package to create a new Excel file when it runs, or do you want it to use an existing Excel file?

Comment: @TabAlleman I have an expression that creates a new file with a timestamp. So a new file yes.

Comment: Does this help?   http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-ms-sql-server-integration-services-2012-create-new-excel-file-dynamically-to-export-data/   or this?   https://www.google.com/search?ei=43DoWrSDIabWjwSdia6oCQ&q=ssis+excel+destination+create+new+file&oq=ssis+excel+destination+tutorial&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0i71k1l8.0.0.0.1637126.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.im3opT5YKWc

Comment: Have you set the package `DelayValidation` to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Set **Validate External Metadata** to **False** and **Delay Validation** to **True** for the Excel destination and then test it. Hope it helps.